# Preparing Mobile Map Package (.mmpk) Popups for Mobile Application

Tags: arcgis-pro, popup, json, html, mobile-map-package

I'm working on creating a new layer for a mobile application built by one of our vendors.  The application uses mobile map packages (.mmpk) for each layer.  I noticed the application's file system is using a .mmpk.json file to drive the popups somehow.  Even though I have configured the popup in ArcGIS Pro and they work fine when reading the .mmpk in Pro itself, but they still do not work within the mobile app (there is some html in the popup, not sure if that matters at all).

I can see the mmpk.json files for the other datasets.  My question is, are these mmpk.json files created uniquely by the mobile application developer, or is this something a GIS analyst can also create?

I'm trying to hack into our product to save a little money since our vendor's contract has already expired.

Comment: mmpk.json does it contain popupElement? https://developers.arcgis.com/web-map-specification/objects/popupElement/

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chitchat like greetings and statements of appreciation in your posts.

Comment: I feel like that is part of the being 'kind' part, though, mate.